# VSTS Extension build summary section

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

I have added a custom summary section to "Build Summary" section through a VSTS extension.

I'm getting following error in VSTS Build summary section on build completion.
[image]

"VSTS Extension by ABC failed to load.Learn More about this extension, including available support options."

Contribution:

```
        "id": "abcfef-build-status-section",
        "type": "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-section",
        "description": "ABC Scan Summary",
        "targets": [
            ".build-info-tab",
            "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-summary-tab"
        ],
        "properties": {
             "name": "ABC Summary Section",
             "uri": "buildstatus.html",
             "order": 20,
             "height": 500
        }
```

Scope:

```
    "scopes": [
  "vso.build",
  "vso.build_execute"
]
```

Html page (buildstatus.html):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
     <title>Hello World</title>
     <script src="scripts/VSS.SDK.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">VSS.init();</script>
     <h1>Hello World</h1>
     <script type="text/javascript">VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Please help to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share your full log of your build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue by analyzing console logs of Chrome browser. It seems my organization firewall is blocking the API call to retrieve resources. :)

https://xxxxxxxx.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=/Extension/status.html Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Thanks-

Answer (score 2):

This is usually caused by the VSS.SDK.js file cannot be loaded when launching the extension, please check the things below:

1. The src path "scripts/VSS.SDK.js" in the html page is correct.
2. The src path and file is included in "files" section in "vss-extension.json" file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this error may occur due to various reasons. In my case I forgot to include scripts folder into "files" in the manifest:

```
    "files": [
    {
        "path": "scripts",
        "addressable": true
    }, ...
```

Hope someone will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As we know, there is an [existing extension sample](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-samples.samples-contributions-guide) for Build Results Enhancer, and the source code can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer

It seems there is nothing wrong with Contribution, you may focus on your Html page, and try to add `usePlatformScripts: true` in your HTML page to see whether the issue persists:

```
 <head>
     <title>Hello World</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <script src="scripts/VSS.SDK.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      VSS.init({
            usePlatformScripts: true
        });
     </script>
     <h1>Hello World</h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```